# Generating public/private key pairs

Tags: ssh

If I generate a key/pair using:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

say, for example. It's not going to overwrite or affect my existing files:

`known_hosts, authorized_keys`

on a test server I'm working on? I just don't want to screw things up by running the above command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It will just create a new set of files, by default named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` and don't touch anything else.

It will even ask before it overwrites a key if you specify a name with the `-f` option.